How to copy the README.md file, inside an angular project before publishing it to npm
I've created a library with Angular libraries
This is my pretty default project structure
- README.md
- package.json
- angular.json
- projects
  - my-project
    - ng-package.json
    - package.json 

When publishing my library over on npm, I do run ng build my-project --configuration production && npm publish ./dist/my-project
It does correctly publish the library, but sadly, the README.md file isn't part of it.
Restrictions

I know, I could copy it inside the my-project folder, but I'd prefer having only one unique README.md file.

Also, I cannot delete the README.md from the root, as it will then be removed from the landing page of the GitHub repository.

assets inside ng-package.json
Sadly this does not work, as I do get Cannot read assets from a location outside of the project root. with the following code


  "assets": [
    "../../README.md"
  ]


Found related github issues, could be a npm caching issue github issue, or some race condition -> github issue

Add a symbolic link to the root README.md from each project directory.

Thx @NarenMurali, but it does not seems to be related, although it is the reason why I initially tried to have only one README file ^^
